# Can't figure out why some of my SQL code doesn't work

Tags: mysql, database, coldfusion, cfml

I'm building an update query with ColdFusion and can't figure out why this piece of code doesn't work? Note, it works directly within mysql server so the SQL must be valid, it just isn't updating my data when called within  tags.

I'm banging my head off the wall over this one and would love to get the help of someone out there that has an idea. My feeling is that ColdFusion is messing the format before it reaches the DB. Thanks you all for your time.

```
<cfquery name="qry" datasource="uf">
UPDATE users set expiry = (SELECT DATE_ADD("#user_qry.expiry#", INTERVAL 10 DAY)), active = 1 where user_id = #user_id#
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I bet `#user_qry.expiry#` is not what you think it is. Add `result="sqlStmt"` to your `<cfquery>` and dump it after the query `<cfdump var="#sqlStmt#">`. It will show you the statement sent to the MySQL server.

Comment: Not familiar with coldfusion, but is that lone `"` supposed to be there before `#user_qry.expiry`?

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo edited now. Not wasn't the issue anyway, I freshly typed the code here and left that out my bad on that one.

Comment: @Alex I'll give your suggestion a go. Thanks guys.

Comment: I always suggest in cases like this that you profile the query that was sent to the database to see exactly how your application built it. Usually, the problem then becomes apparent. SQL Server comes with a profiling tool, but if you Google Profiler for mySQl , you will find several tools available to use. Having not used any, I can't make a recommendation.

Comment: Not overly familiar with mySQL, but in simplifying the statement, do you need the `select` since `date_add` is a function?

Comment: @Alex, you were right man. Thank you!. Believe it or not DATE_ADD() didn't like a timestamp string like so: {ts '2015-12-09 06:20:34'}... I had to build the date and time section of the stamp and cut out the {ts''}.......    Code that worked <cfquery name="qry" datasource="uf" result="res">
 update users set expiry = (SELECT DATE_ADD("#y#-#m#-#d# 00:00:00", INTERVAL 10 DAY)), active = 1 where user_id = 15
</cfquery>

Comment: @TrevorKeating You could just use `#dateFormat(user_qry.expiry, "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00")#`. ;)

Comment: @TrevorKeating You're mixing CF and MySQL date logic. I'd stick to just one. Use `SELECT dateAdd("d",10,CreateODBCDate(user_qry.expiry))... `. Also, you want a cfqueryparam in your WHERE statement. Make sure you sanitize your inputs.

Comment: This way, with CF's `dateAdd()`, you're adding 10 days to a CF date object inside of CF rather than trying to get MySQL to add 10 days to a date string generated by CF.

Comment: Did you try a query parameter instead of all that string manipulation?

Comment: @Shawn thank you for your help and have used your solution, yes I always used cfqueryparam to prevent injection too as a security measure, thanks again.

Comment: To help future answer seekers, I've moved my comment to an Answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing CF and MySQL date logic. I'd stick to just one. Use `SELECT dateAdd("d",10,CreateODBCDate(user_qry.expiry))...`. This way, with CF's dateAdd(), you're adding 10 days to a CF date object inside of CF rather than trying to get MySQL to add 10 days to a date string generated by CF.

Also, you want a cfqueryparam in your WHERE statement. Make sure you sanitize your inputs.